# vim: automatic date/timetamp when opening a specific file?

Tags: vim, autocmd

I would like help with my vim script. thus far I am able to check for the file name, however, I have been unsuccessful in learning how to give normal mode commands via vim script. here is what I've got:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if @% == 'diary.md' | :r! | endif
```

I am trying to give the command :r! to add the date/time on a new line when I open this file.

I appreciate any and all wisdom, thanks~!

Comment: Well, `:r!` expects an external command but we don't know what systems you would use that on so it's hard to give you a definitive answer. On unix-derivatives, you would probably use `$ man date`. Or you could use the built-in `:help :put`, `:help localtime()`, and `:help strftime()` instead for better portability.

Answer (score 2):

From [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12222/7339), a seemingly easy answer:

```
 autocmd VimEnter dairy.md | 0put=strftime('%c')
```

You just have to use the filename, the zero indicates the very beginning of the file. If you want to modificate the timestamp just read the `strftime` help for that.

Comment: thank you so much~! may if I may bother you a bit more, how do you recommend I go about learning more vimscript? at the moment I just googl search like mad, is there a better method? thanks in advance~!

Comment: Actually I recommend learning neovim with lua settings, because luajit is almost faster than vim9, which is still a project for better vimscript. Neovim has in my view a more open community, specially when it comes to the developing model.

Answer (score 1):

huge thanks to @romaini and @SergioAraujo~!

@romaini - your comment helped me learn more about external commands and using the built in :help

@SergioAraujo - your answer was right on the money~! the only issue was that I received the following error with your code:

E116: Invalid Arguments for function strftime(

It was a quick fix though by switching from ("%c") to ('%c') :

```
autocmd VimEnter diary.md | $put=strftime('%c')
```

I am unsure why it only works with single quotes

Additionally, you will note I used $put instead of 0put, this is because I wanted to add the timestamp at the end of the file as a way to start a new entry of my diary on this document. Once again thank you for all your help~!

Comment: You must probably put your thanks in comments